# Confusion about Geometric Series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Context:Problem involving the MGF of a die toss

$M_x(t)=\sum^6_{i=1}e^{tx}\cdot p(x)=e^{t}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+e^{2t}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+...e^{6t}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot e^t \frac{e^{6t}-1}{e^t-1}$

I'm having some difficulty understanding with this is true. I do understand that you can factor out $\frac{1}{6}e^t$, but I don't understand why the remaining sum turns into $\frac{e^{6t}-1}{e^t-1}$.

I have found 2 explanations, one of them seems to fit this, and the other doesn't and I'm having  difficulty understanding when it is one would use one vs. the other

Option 1 (doesn't work, the terms are backward): $\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}ar^k=a\cdot\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$

Option 2 (does work): $\sum_{k=1}^nx^k=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}$

While it would seem that I had found my answer in option 2, I guess I am confused because nearly every source I could find online cited option 1, while option 2 I could only find once. Is this indeed a legitimate series, can I assume that it is usable to solve my given problem?

Comment: As for the terms being backward in Option 1, note that $$\frac{a-b}{c-d}=\frac{-1}{-1}\cdot\frac{a-b}{c-d}=\frac{-1\cdot(a-b)}{-1\cdot(c-d)}=\frac{b-a}{d-c}$$ Thus, it's legal to change the order of the subtractions, so long as you do so in both the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to use the first formula.

Now, $a= \frac16 e^t, r = e^t, n = 6$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^5 ar^k = \frac16 e^t \cdot \frac{1-e^{6t}}{1-e^t}=\frac16 e^t \cdot \frac{e^{6t}-1}{e^t-1}$$

Notice that $\frac{c}{d}= \frac{-c}{-d}$.